# New to Xcode/swift and need help showing/hiding images with a switch

Tags: xcode

Only know JavaScript and just started working on Xcode so very slowly figuring it out but need help using a switch to hide/show an image. Already inserted the images and switches onto the storyboard just need help with the coding commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create IBOutlets in your ViewController and connect them to your storyboard views by right clicking them and dragging the `New Referencing Outlet` option to associated line:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var visibilitySwitch: UISwitch!
```

And an IBAction for your switch:

```
@IBAction func updateVisibility(_ sender: Any) {
    imageView.isHidden = !visibilitySwitch.isOn
}
```

Connect the IBAction to the `ValueChanged` Action also by right clicking and dragging to the method:

[image]

Comment: Sorry I am still very lost.

Comment: There are more details here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html